# can someone please explain this simple code to ? scroll indicator

Tags: javascript

this a simple code a found in the internet to create a scroll indicator but the problem is that I don't understand the logic behind it.... why subtract max Height and inner Height and after that use the result for division , and why multiplying by 100 what is the logic behind this ?
P.S. I know that :
`scrollHeight` is to return full height of the HTMLdocument.
`innerHeight` returns the height of the viewable window (with the scrollbar)
`pageYoffset` is the same thing as ScrollY returns number of pixels scrolled
it's a matter of why using not how to use....

```js
const progressbar = document.querySelector('.scroll--progress');

const scroll = () => {
  // return the scroll height of the entier page
  const maxHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
  //return the innerheight of the ViewPort
  const inner = window.innerHeight;

  const a = maxHeight - innerHeight;
  const t = Math.round(window.pageYOffset);
  const b = (window.scrollY / a) * 100;
  //setup the progress bar width
  progressbar.style.width = `${b}` + '%';
};

window.addEventListener('scroll', scroll);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's better cross-compatibility with the use of pageYOffset; I'd not use the scrollY unless there's a scenario that proves it useful. Rare browser-cases?

scrollY and pageYOffset are the same! But all browsers on MDN support pageYOffset.

Comment: We divide offsets and multiply them by 100 for % 1-100. There's no more logic. We require these offsets so we're not including pixels that aren't apart of the "screen".

Comment: what are offsets ?